# Move all my commits from one repo to another

Tags: git

I committed a few times to a common repository, together with several other authors. Now I want to build my own repository, out of **only my own** commits. I am not really sure how to start, since I need to keep the original history intact.

Comment: If you ever merged your changes in with others', good luck.

Comment: If you've committed from an existing code base, then ipso facto you'll be building on top of commits that are not yours. I would create another fork of that repository and then reset to a commit that I want to start from afresh - to wipe out the work of everyone else. Then you'll have your own version of that repository without it being polluted by the work of other people.

Comment: Git's a full-service history-construction toolkit, but your question leaves out crucial details.  What exactly do you want to preserve?  Draw the history graph you're starting with and the history graph you want, and explain how the content of the commits you want relates to the content in the commits you have.

Comment: By preserving history I mean preserving the date and changes for my own commits. And only move these commits to the new repository. I basically need a filter that only returns (and moves) my commits between two repos.

Answer (score 1):

This is quite unorthodox issue.

Is this common repository some sort of a project or loose set of unrelated files?

If the files are unrelated (by that I mean you were not working on someone else's code/files) then you can filter and gather your commits using combination of `git filter-branch` and `git cherry-pick` followed by `git format-patch` that you can later apply on top of your new repo.

Roughly it might look like this:

1. Find out hashes of your commits with for instance with `git log`. Let's say one commit has `SHA` equal to `b33787c`
2. `Cherry pick` it with `git cherry-pick b33787c`
3. Create patch for this commit: `git format-patch -1 b33787c`. This will result in a creation of `0001-COMMIT-NAME.patch` that you can later reuse.

If, however, the files you were working one belong to one cohesive project I do not think it can be done in a way this code would be `useful/functional` after such operation.

Comment: Indeed, my commits only contain changes to my files, so moving my commits will result in the right outcome. I am not sure how can I use the three commands you mentioned.

Comment: @linkyndy one of the way of filtering branches is mentioned in CodeWizard answer. I will edit my answer to give you a few more tips how can this be done in a different way though.

Comment: @linkyndy please have a look now.

Comment: I don't think cherry pick is scalable here, I have many potential commits to move.

Comment: @linkyndy why not? You just do it in a loop in a bash script, obviously I didn't want you to do it manually :)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new repo and than filter out the commits where you was the author with the `git filter-branch`

something like:

```
git filter-branch --commit-filter '
    if [ "$GIT_COMMITTER_NAME" = "<Your name>" ];
    then
        # use this commit 
    fi' HEAD `
```

Comment: What should I replace the comment with?

Answer (score 0):

**Make a file ready to Move:**

Make a copy of repository A so you can mess with it without worrying about mistakes too much.  It’s also a good idea to delete the link to the original repository to avoid accidentally making any remote changes (line 3).  Line 4 is the critical step here.  It goes through your history and files, removing anything that is not in directory 1.  The result is the contents of directory 1 spewed out into to the base of repository A.  You probably want to import these files into repository B within a directory, so move them into one now (lines 5/6). Commit your changes and we’re ready to merge these files into the new repository.

```
 1. git clone <git repository A url>
 2. cd <git repository A directory>
 3. git remote rm origin
 4. git filter-branch --subdirectory-filter <directory 1> -- --all
 5. mkdir <directory 1>
 6. mv * <directory 1>
 7. git add .
 8. git commit
```

**Merge file into new repository:**

Make a copy of repository B if you don’t have one already.  On line 3, you’ll create a remote connection to repository A as a branch in repository B.  Then simply pull from this branch (containing only the directory you want to move) into repository B.  The pull copies both files and history.  Note: You can use a merge instead of a pull, but pull worked better for me. Finally, you probably want to clean up a bit by removing the remote connection to repository A. Commit and you’re all set.

```
 1. git clone <git repository B url>
 2. cd <git repository B directory>
 3. git remote add repo-A-branch <git repository A directory>
 4. git pull repo-A-branch master
 5. git remote rm repo-A-branch
```

**Moving the commits from A to B repository**

1. Check the whole tree.

   `git log --all --oneline --graph --decorate --abbrev-commit`
2. copy (cherry-pick) the commits from the A repo into B repo.

   `git cherry-pick sha-of-commit-one
       git cherry-pick sha-of-commit-two
       git cherry-pick sha-of-commit-three`
3. check your local repo is correct.

   `git log`
4. send your new tree (repo state) to new repository.

   `git push origin master`
5. remove the now-unneeded reference to oldrepo A.

   `git remote remove oldrepo A`

**for particular author moving comments from A to B Repo**

1. Find all commits by author and save their hash to a file:

   `git log --author=<author> --format=%H > /tmp/commit-by-author`
2. Create a new branch that does not contain this particular's author
   commit . For this, you can create a new empty branch:

   `git checkout --orphan commits-by-author`
3. Cherry-pick all commits of that author (from A to B Repo):

   `tac /tmp/commit-by-x | while read sha; do git cherry-pick ${sha}`; 
   done

Comment: This looks good, except the fact that I would prefer to filter on my commits, not on a folder. I might have renamed the folder in the meantime (though it is still just me who committed within it).

Comment: @linkyndy i have edited my answer to move only comments from repo A to repo B.

Comment: This is not really scalable, check my comment to the other answer. There are many commits and I would like to automate this selection based on the commit author.

Comment: @linkyndy how you want to move comments i mean select comments by user or date ? ....

Comment: Indeed, I need to filter commits by author.